# Echo length of a variable from the windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, windows-console

So I'm looking for a quick command to evaluate the length of environment variables on the windows command line.

Conceptually, something to the effect of:

```
echo %PATH%.length
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :COUNT "%path%"
echo Your variable is %length% characters long
pause >nul

:COUNT
set temp=%1
set length=0
:loop
if defined temp (
    set temp=!temp:~1!
    set /a length+=1
    goto :loop
)
```

Usage: `call :COUNT %yourvar%` and the length will be stored in `%length%`.

Comment: A little hack-y but I'll take it! Thanks for the quick and concise answer!